# Why do I have a problem selecting a button in a lua script?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to select a button in lua and then to click in that button, but I'm getting the following error:

> Bad request to Splash: {'error': 400, 'type': 'ScriptError', 'description': 'Error happened while executing Lua script', 'info'

My code is here:

```
btn = assert(splash:select(button.button-reset.filter__options-button))
```

In the following picture is the button that I need to select:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know splash, but this is causing a syntax error:

```
btn = assert(splash:select(button.button-reset.filter__options-button))
```

You cannot have a minus in a Lua identifier.

```
button.button-reset.filter__options-button
```

Either this is supposed to be a string:

```
btn = assert(splash:select("button.button-reset.filter__options-button"))
```

or you need to use proper indexing for those tables

```
btn = assert(splash:select(button["button-reset"]["filter__options-button"]))
```

I can't tell what is the correct solution without digging into the splash documentation but that's the only two ways that would not cause syntax errors.

A quick look into the docs suggests that this needs to be a CSS selector as a string. So probably the first solution is correct, assuming that you provided a valid CSS selector.